# Some question of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, notation, ideals

$I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$ and $x$ is an element of $R$.

What is the meaning of the sign : $(I,x)$ ?

I know the sign : $$(I:x):=\{r:\, rx\in I\}$$
but what is the meaning of $(I,x)$ ?

Comment: Possibly the ideal generated by $I$ and $x$.

Comment: or explicitly $\{i+rx, i\in I, r\in R\}$.

Comment: ...which is more commonly denoted as $I+(x)$ or $I+xR$.

Comment: It is also sometimes denoted as $\langle I, x \rangle$

Comment: in fact ,I red something about the Lasker-Nother theory ,but I can not understand one sentence;https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Commutative_Algebra/Primary_decomposition_or_Lasker%E2%80%93Noether_theory;  the prove of theorem 19.14 ,it said  if q is a ideal and x is not in q,  then r(q)=r((q,x))  r(q)is the radical ideal of q, why??

Comment: who can explain the prove of theorem 19.14 ,especially the last two sentences of the provement;